# Cell Address not return correctly VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to multiply variable with another workbook cell reference in current workbook. the `Outstval` address printed as `$N$28` and call that in multiplication without absolute reference, it return `P32`.

```
Sub dummy()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim A1, Outst, Outstval As Range

Dim PTC As Integer

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashokkumar.d\Desktop\New folder (2)\20170221_Par Mosec Marquez Waterfall (1T SLCE) - EIS.xlsb")

PTC = 1
With ActiveSheet
    Set A1 = .UsedRange.find("SERIES A1")

    Set Outst = A1.Offset(1, 0)
    Set Outstval = Outst.Offset(2, 0)
    Debug.Print Outstval.Address  /  printing address is $N$28
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("C5").Formula = "= ( " & PTC & "*" & Outstval.Address(False, Flase, xlExternal) & " )"
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

in C5 cell having formula  = `( 1*'[20170221_Par Mosec Marquez Waterfall (1T SLCE) - EIS.xlsb]Waterfall'!P32 )`...

Why `P32` coming  instead of `N28` ?

Comment: Remove the part .Address(False, Flase, xlExternal) and see what do you get?

Comment: @sktneer  getting only value

Comment: @Ashok try using `.Range("C5").Formula = "= ( " & PTC & "*" & Outstval.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal) & " )"`